# Incorrect Syntax near '=' (not an issue with "similiar" characters)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know that this probably has been answered before, but I have rewritten this single line 10 times it still won't work. I have assured myself that this is written properly, yet it won't work.

This is my last resort. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that set `findItForMe`?

Comment: Syntax error is in the SQL code, not the C# code.  Check `findItForMe.CommandText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, and for the exact reason you are asking, you should not be setting raw T-SQL in the`CommandText` property of your `SqlCommand`.

In your case, your string likely has `'` characters in it that are breaking your query making the syntax invalid.

Instead, you CommandText should be initialized with Parameters, for example:

```
findItForMe.CommandText = "SELECT Name, LicenseType, till FROM myTable WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeParameter"
```

Then in your `findItForMe` command add the Parameters.

```
findItForMe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeParameter", Somevalue)
```

Building your `findItForMe` `SqlCommand` this way will fix your errors and prevent malicious actors from perform SQL injection hacks against your application.

A full example:

```
string name = "Jacob's Ladder";
string commandText = "SELECT Name, LicenseType, till FROM myTable WHERE Name = @Name";


using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand findItForMe = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);



    // Use AddWithValue to assign name
    // The parameterized query will escape your strings and keep you safe from hackers.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```